# How can i print out my bitcoin address that resides on my android phone?

Tags: wallet

I run a repair shop and im thinking of taking bitcoins, but I want to get the QR image of my wallet address onto my site. The wallet address is on my phone, but I'm not sure how or where I can go to print out the QR image of my address. I did a google search, but everyone has a wallet generator. I just want to print out an existing address i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do it:

```
<img src="http://qrfree.kaywa.com/?l=1&s=8&d=$yourAddressHere" alt="QRCode"/>
```